# Perforce connection problems (in WebStorm) (Invalid command: -zprog=intellij_idea_info)

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, perforce

So I'm getting an error every time I try to connect to perforce through WebStorm. Here's an image of my settings:

[image]

When I use "Test Connection", I get a pop-up that says `Connection Problems: No client name in info specification found`.

Here's the p4.output and idea.log output after clicking "Test Connection"

**p4.output**

```
10:19:13 info 
10:19:13 
ErrCode=255
StdOut:------------
Unknown command or option flag passed.
p4vc help for usage.
Invalid command: -zprog=intellij_idea_info
StdErr:------------

End----------------
```

**idea.log**

```
2018-05-09 10:19:13,878 [7216927]   INFO - lication.PerforceInfoAndClient - No client name in info specification found 
com.intellij.openapi.vcs.VcsException: No client name in info specification found
    at org.jetbrains.idea.perforce.application.PerforceInfoAndClient.extractClient(PerforceInfoAndClient.java:41)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.perforce.application.PerforceInfoAndClient.calcInfo(PerforceInfoAndClient.java:27)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.perforce.application.PerforceInfoAndClient.calculateInfos(PerforceInfoAndClient.java:101)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.perforce.perforce.ConfigPanel$2.lambda$actionPerformed$1(ConfigPanel.java:130)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:247)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:750)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$5.run(CoreProgressManager.java:434)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.a(ApplicationImpl.java:565)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:305)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've tried using a P4CONFIG file instead of the manual inputs, but WebStorm can't find any of my configuration settings (which is really frustrating as well). Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it would help if I pointed the p4 executable path to the actual p4 command. I'm on MacOS so I ran `which p4` in the terminal, got the path (in my case the path was `/usr/local/bin/p4`), placed that in the `Path to P4 executable` input box, and everything worked fine!

Comment: Correct. p4 is quite a different piece of software than p4vc.